# ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module uses module.id for css-loader?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, css-loader

I'm getting `ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module uses module.id`, I think it's because of `css-loader`:

```
Child mini-css-extract-plugin ../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-1!routes/LoginRouteStyles.css:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    [1] ../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-1!./routes/LoginRouteStyles.css 781 bytes {0} [built]
        ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module uses module.id
        + 1 hidden module
```

And my Webpack config file:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: [APP_ROOT],
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          esModule: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

It looks like css-loader is using `module.id` here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/df7960277be20ec80e9be1a41ac53baf69847fa0/src/utils.js#L247

Is there a way to get `ModuleConcatenationPlugin` to work with `css-loader`?